Trace Curves from moving point with Geometry Nodes
I am trying to trace out the position of a point moving around 3d space into a curve using geometry nodes. I have a series of instanced lines rotating to create a fourier series. I now want to take the endpoint of the final line and use it's point position per frame to generate a new curve to create a trace.
I am struggling with using repeat or simulation zones becuase the rotation is controlled by scene time, and sample curve with factor set to one gives me a point cloud with a single point that just updates is position over time.
I want to take that point at time 0 and put it into a list at index 0, and then append a new point to that list on the next frame, but I'm struggling with implementing that in geometry nodes.

Thanks!

Just join point after point after point and make a curve


Wow, really was that simple. Join goes in the simulation zone, not sample. Thanks!!!!

I just think I might have joined in reverse (the point noodle is going above the geometry noodle)

I think we should close the question as a duplicate of Create Curve from Path of an Object Using Geometry Nodes but problem is, it doesn't a have a simulation zone solution as on of the answers, which is the best solution currently...
